# Create and keep state across several tests

Tags: c++, googletest

In Microsofts cpp unit test framework, it is possible to initialize (and cleanup) things exactly one time for several tests:

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
TEST_CLASS(MyTestClass)
{
public:
    TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(InitForAllTests)
    {
         // Do something exactly one time for all tests in this class.
         // This is run before the first test starts.
    }
    TEST_CLASS_CLEANUP(CleanupForAllTests)
    {
        // This is run after the last test of the class has finished executing.
    }
    // Contains a lot of tests.
};
```

Is something similar built in Google test?

The test fixture class does not fit, since the object is recreated for every test, therefore the constructor/destructor and `SetUp()`/`TearDown()` is run for every test (like `TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE`, `TEST_METHOD_CLEANUP` of the MS cpp unit test framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`SetUpTestSuite()` and `TearDownTestSuite()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite) (previously
`SetUpTestCase()` and `TearDownTestCase()` in googletest < v1.8). For
example:

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct test_suite_one : public ::testing::Test {
    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        ++suite_resource;
        std::cout << "suite_resource=" << suite_resource << std::endl;
    }

    static void TearDownTestSuite() {
        suite_resource = 0;
        std::cout << "suite_resource=" << suite_resource << std::endl;
    }
    void SetUp() override {
        ++test_resource;
        std::cout << "test_resource=" << test_resource << std::endl;
    }
    void TearDown(){}
protected:
    unsigned test_resource = 0;
    static unsigned suite_resource;
};

unsigned test_suite_one::suite_resource;

TEST_F(test_suite_one,test_one) {
    ASSERT_EQ(test_resource,1);
    ASSERT_TRUE(suite_resource == test_resource);
    ++suite_resource;
    std::cout << "suite_resource=" << suite_resource << std::endl;
}

TEST_F(test_suite_one,test_two) {
    ASSERT_EQ(test_resource,1);
    ASSERT_TRUE(suite_resource > test_resource);
    std::cout << "suite_resource=" << suite_resource << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

which runs like:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o gtester gtester.cpp -lgtest -pthread
$ ./gtester 
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from test_suite_one
suite_resource=1
[ RUN      ] test_suite_one.test_one
test_resource=1
suite_resource=2
[       OK ] test_suite_one.test_one (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] test_suite_one.test_two
test_resource=1
suite_resource=2
[       OK ] test_suite_one.test_two (0 ms)
suite_resource=0
[----------] 2 tests from test_suite_one (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [test environment](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down) to do global set-up and tear-down.